# 2012 Jeep Wrangler JKU turn signal, horn and wipers stopped working

Tags: jeep, windshield-wipers, wrangler

How can I fix my 2012 Jeep Wrangler JKU when the turn signal, horn and wipers stopped working. It doesn't seem to be a fuse as those elements are on separate fuses. This started happening when I drove up Pikes Peak but I don't know if the altitude can effect the electronics in that way.

Comment: One of the first rules in troubleshooting is eliminate the obvious, even if it is unlikely, so I suggest you check the fuses anyway. If all three did go there would likely be one central cause. The turn signal and wipers are all on one stick, correct? What about your other electronics?

Comment: Disconecting the battery worked for me as well!!

Comment: The above that said to "reboot"---unhook battery and wait ten minutes then hook back up---sure enough worked on mine!!! The turn signal lights quit flashing on the dash as well as the front and rear turn signal lights themselves....worked fine after the "reboot" ---- Thanks for that insight!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found at least one solution that seems to have worked. Unhook the battery, wait 10 minutes and then hook it back up. This forces a computer reset and magically everything started working again. When in doubt reboot!

Comment: I have a 2011 Jeep Wrangler and my horn, windshield wipers, blinkers and headlights stop working. I tried the suggestion of unhooking the battery for 10 minutes and re-hooking them back up and it worked. Thank you Stimy for saving me from having to bring it to the shop!!!